# Android 10: cordova-plugin-mfilechose is not working

Tags: android, cordova, ionic4

I'm using [cordova-plugin-mfilechose](https://github.com/Evolution-36/MFileChooser#readme) in my Ionic 4 application. It works fine till Android version 9. But in Android 10 whenever we trigger the plugin it just opens a window saying Internal storage but no file is listed, though there are many files inside the phone. I have used the same code as per the official documentation, added below. Thanks in advance.

```
window.plugins.mfilechooser.open(['.doc', '.xls', '.ppt'], function (uri) {

  alert(uri);

}, function (error) {

    alert(error);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The plugin looks like it is using standard Java File operations and paths to choose files, in Android 10 and above you cannot use file paths or Java File operations any more on anything but your App's private directory.

See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped

Also not sure why you would use such a plugin as Android provides the functions natively with Storage Access FrameWork(SAF) or MediaStore

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider#client
on how.

Everything can now only work with Java `FileDescriptor`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But since it is a Hybrid app with Ionic framework, I need to use some plugins to achieve native functionality. My requirement is achieved using the above plugin. Are you aware of any plugin or modification to existing plugin to work in Android 10 ?

Comment: I don't use Ionic Framework, so I'm not aware of a plugin that would work, BUT there is a temporary fix you can add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to the applications manifest as per https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped#opt-out-of-scoped-storage . This will work for Android 10 but not Android 11, this will allow you time to raise a feature request with the plugin to be compatible.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I will check what can I do to modify the plugin so that it start supporting the latest storage guildlines.

Comment: Really the plugin needs to become just an interface wrapper with very little functionality itself, it just needs to adapter it's current API to the SAF/Mediastore API. The role of third party file choosers is redundant in Android 10

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to my problem. Though it is not a solution in long run. In my Ionic 4 project project/config.xml android-targetSdkVersion was 29. I changed it to 28. Which works on Android 10 and also on all the lower versions. Below is the code.

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
```

Comment: No, I don't think so. Because when I tested by changing the value to 28, the app won't even load.

Answer (score 0):

I think all ionic plugins like cordova-plugin-camera and cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker needs to update to fully compatible with android 10 for scoped storage.

Comment: That's true, most plugins are outdated, last commits are few years back. Ionic promoting pro features and Capacitor and not showing any interest in interacting with authors to keep cordova plugins up to date.